# CLI/C++. How to refer to box using name stored in variable?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, textbox, c++-cli

I am using Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express, and i was wondering if its possible to refer to some box (textbox, picture box, whateverbox) using a word/number stored in variable. For example:

```
textBox1 -> Text = "I fill textBox1 with some text";
```

same as

```
string ^ name = "textBox";
int number = 1;
name+number -> Text = "I fill textBox1 with some text";
```

So, can i achieve that somehow? I am asking cuz i have multiple boxes i would like to change in a loop (for or while) increasing number variable and i dont want to write every box name everytime, that looks awfull in code, and probably isnt the best idea to do that :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple textboxes you are better of storing them in an array of some kind so that you can refer to them as `textbox[0]` , `textbox[1]` etc etc

or do them in a loop like

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i )
     textbox[i]->Text = "Bar";
```

Comment: Well yeah, that's good idea too(or even better than mine). But for this one, i have no idea how to put these textboxes to an array so i could refer to them like you said.

Comment: textbox = new TextBox[] { textBox1, textBox2, etcetera };  Put it in constructor after InitializeComponent().

Comment: Oh, the C++/CLI version of that :)